# Python dict: print unique entries based on value

Tags: python

I'm making a script which fetches movies and shows from different services. I need a functionality where if a movie is available on a streaming platform (e.g. Paramount) in both 4k and HD, then I want to only show 4K result.
However, If the title is only available for purchase, then I want to exclude that from the results.

```py
resp = {
    # Fetches JSON response as dict from server 
    # which contains offers as a list of dictionaries
    "offers": [
        {
            "monetization_type": "flatrate",
            "package_short_name": "pmp",
            "presentation_type": "4k",
        },
        {
            "monetization_type": "flatrate",
            "package_short_name": "pmp",
            "presentation_type": "hd",
        },
        {
            "monetization_type": "flatrate",
            "package_short_name": "fxn",
            "presentation_type": "hd",
        },
        {
            "monetization_type": "buy",
            "package_short_name": "itu",
            "presentation_type": "4k",
        },
    ]
}
    
def get_Stream_info(obj, results=[]):
    try:
        if obj["offers"]:
            count = 0
            for i in range(len(obj["offers"])):
                srv = obj["offers"][i]["monetization_type"]
                qty = obj["offers"][i]["presentation_type"]
                pkg = obj["offers"][i]["package_short_name"]
                if srv == "flatrate" and qty in ["4k", "hd"]:
                    results.append(f"Stream [{i+1}]: US - {pkg} - {qty}")
                    count = 1
                else:
                    errstr = f"No streaming options available."
        if count == 0:
            results.append(errstr)
    except KeyError:
        results.append(f"Not available.")
    return "\n".join(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_Stream_info(resp))
```

Result:

```py
Stream [1]: US - pmp - 4k # ParamountPlus
Stream [2]: US - pmp - hd # ParamountPlus
Stream [3]: US - fxn - hd # FoxNow
```

4K and HD are available on ParamountPlus but I only want to print 4K.

Finally HD on all others where 4K isn't available.

Comment: replace the if statement with "if monetize == 'flatrate' and qty == "4k":"

Comment: @Noah then it won't print the `fxn` stream which is in hd

Comment: But if it is available in only one format, you want it anyway, right? So you have to  detect when there is only one format for a given short name. That means making 2 passes through the data. One to identify which short names have 2 formats and which have only one. Then a second pass to pick the right format if there are 2 and print it, or print whatever there is if there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a dictionary that rates the qualities? Could be good if you later have streams that are SD or other formats. That way you are always showing only the best quality stream from each service with minimal code:

```
qty_ratings = {
    '4k': 1,
    'hd': 2,
    'sd': 3
}
```

Append the highest quality stream:

```
if monetize == 'flatrate':  
            # Check if there are more than one stream from the same service
            if len(qty) > 1:
                qty = min([qty_ratings[x] for x in qty])
            result.append(f"Stream {[i]}: US - {service} - {qty}")

    return "\n".join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would explicitly sort the streams, not because it's more efficient, but because it makes it clear what I'm doing.

Assuming your offers are defined as in the question:

```py
ranking = ("sd", "hd", "4k")

def get_best_stream(streams):
    return max(streams, key=lambda x: ranking.index(x["presentation_type"]))


get_best_stream(offers)
```

As @Gustaf notes, this is forward compatible.  I've used a tuple rather than a dict since we really only care about order (perhaps even more explicit would be an enum).

If you want to keep one offer from every source, I would encode this explicitly:

```py
def get_streams(streams):
    sources = set(x["package_short_name"] for x in streams)
    return [
        get_best_stream(s for s in streams if s["package_short_name"] == source)
        for source in sources
    ]



get_streams(offers)
```

Of course if you have billions of streams it would be more efficient to build a mapping between source and offers, but for a few dozen the cost of an iterator is trivial.